# Django why does this line from urls.py have invalid syntax?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

```
     (r'^picks/(?P<choice>\w+)/$', 'app.views.picks', name='needed_picks'),
```

This line is giving me an invalid syntax error for some reason.. ideas??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are confusing your [url patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#django.conf.urls.url), to use name it must be

```
url(r'^picks/(?P<choice>\w+)/$', 'app.views.picks', name='needed_picks'),
```